# Parsing XML with a lot of children nodes to UITableView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xml, cocoa-touch

I have an xml file that looks like this:

```
<result>
<trip duration="03:30">
<takeoff date="2010-06-19" time="18:40" city="Moscow"/>
<landing date="2010-06-19" time="20:10" city="Novgorod"/>
<flight carrier="Rossiya" number="8395" eq="320"/>
<price>13429.00</price>
</trip>
<trip duration="03:40">
<takeoff date="2010-06-19" time="09:20" city="Omsk"/>
<landing date="2010-06-19" time="11:15" city="Paris"/>
<flight carrier="AirFrance" number="1145" eq="320"/>
<price>13229.00</price>
</trip>
<trip duration="03:50">
<takeoff date="2010-06-19" time="07:20" city="Omsk"/>
<landing date="2010-06-19" time="14:15" city="Barcelona"/>
<flight carrier="AirFrance" number="1100" eq="320"/>
<price>13329.00</price>
</trip>
</result>
```

I'd like to get all the parameters and place them in 3 UITableViewCells. As you can see there are 3 flights and the data about them.
I've been trying to parse it in a TableView but I only managed to get the `<price>` thing going.
How would you deal with parsing complex-structured parameters within an XML file? I mean how would I get `takeoff date` parameter and so on and so forth?
As far as I could get you can't apply the tactics I'm using like this one:

```
- (void) parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementname namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName
{
        if ([elementname isEqualToString:@"price"]) 
        {
            currentTweet.dateCreated = currentNodeContent;
        }
```

Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the code that I frequently use to build a dictionary from an XML file that follows this basic model of some well defined repeating element (in this case, `"trip"`), and a series of data elements within that, some of which I'm reading the attributes of the tag (in this case, `"takeoff"`, `"landing"` and `"flight"`), and others I'm reading the data between the opening and closing tags (in this case, just `"price"`).

I have the following ivars:

```
@interface XmlParserViewController () <NSXMLParserDelegate>
{
    NSMutableArray *trips;
    NSMutableDictionary *currentTrip;
    NSMutableString *currentElement;
}
@end
```

And then the code looks like:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    trips = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    // I'm getting my xml from my bundle. You get it however you're currently getting it.

    NSString *filename = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"results" ofType:@"xml"];
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filename];
    NSXMLParser *parser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData:data];
    parser.delegate = self;
    [parser parse];
}

#pragma mark - NSXMLParserDelegate methods

#define kRowElementTag @"trip"

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qualifiedName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict
{
    NSArray *attributeElementNames = @[@"takeoff", @"landing", @"flight"];
    NSArray *foundCharacterElementNames = @[@"price"];

    if ([elementName isEqualToString:kRowElementTag])
    {
        currentTrip = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
        [trips addObject:currentTrip];
        if (attributeDict)
            [currentTrip setObject:attributeDict forKey:elementName];
    }
    else if (currentTrip)
    {
        if ([attributeElementNames containsObject:elementName])
        {
            if (attributeDict)
                [currentTrip setObject:attributeDict forKey:elementName];
        }
        else if ([foundCharacterElementNames containsObject:elementName] && currentElement == nil)
        {
            // you can change this to just grab a few fields ... add whatever fields you want to this

            currentElement = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
            [currentTrip setObject:currentElement forKey:elementName];
        }
    }
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName
{
    if ([elementName isEqualToString:kRowElementTag])
    {
        currentTrip = nil;
    }
    else if (currentElement)
    {
        currentElement = nil;
    }
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string
{
    if (currentElement)
    {
        [currentElement appendString:string];
    }
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser parseErrorOccurred:(NSError *)parseError
{
    NSLog(@"%s error=%@", __FUNCTION__, parseError);

    // we should handle the error here
}

- (void)parserDidEndDocument:(NSXMLParser *)parser
{
    NSLog(@"%s trips=%@", __FUNCTION__, trips);

    // generally I immediately kick off the reload of the table, but maybe 
    // you want to grok the trips dictionary first.
    //        
    // [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

As you can guess, I'm trying to end up with that sort of nested array/dictionary structure that we've gotten used to parsing JSON files. Clearly, I don't like the fact that I have to identify some of the structure of the XML file up front in my code (the fact that the outer array has `"trip"` tags, that `"takeoff"`, `"landing"`, and `"flight"` have attributes but "price"` doesn't), etc. But this is a little better than my first attempts at XML parsing that hardcoded values all over the place. Sigh.

Comment: Thanks for the amazing explanation! I'll definitely try it out.

Comment: I tried it out today and NSLog tells me that 'trips' value is NULL. Any ideas on what I might be doing wrong? I really like your approach but I can't seem to make it work

Comment: @SergiusGee Sounds like you never initialize `trips`. See my `viewDidLoad`, which I just added here (as well as in your other question), where I show you how to sort.

Answer (score 1):

You have to manage didStartElement too. This is a sample metacode could be good for you:

```
-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser*)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString*)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString*)qualifiedName attributes:(NSDictionary*)attributeDict {
    if([elementName isEqualToString:@"trip"]) {
       currentTweet.tripDuration = [attributeDict objectForKey:@"duration"];
    } else if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"takeoff"]) {
       currentTweet.takeoffDate = [attributeDict objectForKey:@"date"];
       currentTweet.takeoffTime = [attributeDict objectForKey:@"time"];
       currentTweet.takeoffCity = [attributeDict objectForKey:@"city"];
    } else if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"landing"]) {
       ...............
    } else if ...........
}
```